# jquery each() doesn't loop through newly added table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple table

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

when i  append another row to the above table with text 5 in td jquery each() doesn't loop through newly added row it returns only predefined elements not the elements dynamically added

```
$("table > tbody").append("<td>5</td>");
$("table tr td").each(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Please see [JS FIDDLE LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/v7znh/1/)

Comment: Your selector is `tr td`, while you directly put the new `<td>` in `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `tbody` you cannot append `td` directly *wrap* them in `tr`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JcvtG/)**

```
$("table > tbody").append("<tr><td>5</td></tr>");
$("table tr td").each(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Chrome lets you do that, even if it's invalid HTML. See the OP's fiddle.

Comment: @Reigel What happened to Kunwari? ;)

Comment: @JanDvorak, yes chrome let's you do that... but the OP's selector will not... imagine, `table tr td`...

Comment: @alex lol... I edited it quickly... but you have a quick eye... :D

Answer (score 5):

Your reasoning is incorrect. The reason it doesn't find the element is because your selector doesn't match the nesting of elements that you're appending.

Wrap the `td` elements in a `tr` element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
$("table > tbody").append("<tr><td>5</td></tr>");
$("table tr td").each(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

The reason is simple you, your original code will produce the new row as `<tbody><td>5</td></tbody>` without the tr tag that you were looking for in the each function.